# How to prevent iOS Zoom on Ionic Alert input field

Tags: ios, reactjs, ionic-framework, mobile-safari, capacitor

I am using Ionic and React to develop a cross platform mobile app. The issue I am having is on iOS (which uses Safari for the webview), when the user taps on a text input field in an IonAlert, the app zooms in to the alert. Then, when the user hits either the 'Save' or 'Cancel' buttons, the app zooms in even more and requires restart of the app to rectify. I tried searching for Safari solutions, and the ones I have found have not worked for me (such as the maximum-scale=1 solution). Maybe I'm not sure where to put something like that given that I'm working with JSX and not html, and there aren't property fields like that for me to use, and I did not notice anything that stood out to me on the Ionic documentation for this component.

Here is the code for the alert. I'm hoping someone with Ionic experience can help me learn what is going on here:

```
            <IonAlert
                isOpen={showAlert}
                onDidDismiss={() => setShowAlert(false)}
                buttons={[
                    {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        role: 'cancel',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Save',
                        role: 'save',
                        handler: (e) => {
                            saveHandler(e[0]);
                        },
                    },
                ]}
                header={`Change ${type}`}
                inputs={
                    [
                        {
                            type: type === 'Name' ? 'text' : 'tel', 
                            placeholder: getPlaceHolder(),
                        },
                    ]
                }
            >
            </IonAlert>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an ionic app, it automatically creates the next line inside index.html,

this line works:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

maybe you have the next line (does not work ):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```